# check if username exists

Tags: php, mysql

Im making a registration script for my site and i want to check if $_POST['username'] does already exist in db.

Is there a better, less code way of doing it? I do the same for email.

This is how it looks like now:

```
$checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'");
$row83 = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkusername);

if ($_POST['username'] == $row83['username']) die('Username already in use.');
```

Comment: I hope you have no users named '; drop table users --

Comment: leeeroy brings up a very important point... check all input from the UI and never trust it.  If you don't, someone can inject SQL into your SELECT statement that will trash your DB.  For a humorous angle on this, see http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_isk1o8_XWYA/R0ML6q6-HYI/AAAAAAAAAtY/_bm0dffd6Gc/s1600-h/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: @Eric J, credit where credit's due: http://xkcd.com/327/ the comic is, if you didn't know, XKCD authored by Randall Munroe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [`unique constraint`](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_unique.asp) onto your table:

```
alter table users
add unique (username)
```

Then, your `insert` or `update` statements will fail out:

```
mysql_query("insert into users (username) values ('$username')")
   or die('Username exists');
```

Of course, a bigger issue with your code is that you aren't preventing SQL injection. Your code should be:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
mysql_query("insert into users (username) values ('$username')")
   or die('Username exists');
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are already checking the username in the sql call, then you really just need to see if a record is returned in the php side of things

```
$row83 = mysql_query($checkusername);
if (mysql_num_rows($row83) == 0) die('Username already in use.');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set username as "unique" in your database you can just go ahead and run the insert query, which will fail (which you can handle). The same goes for email - make it "unique".

[This](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/add_unique.htm) may come in handy.